# Js delay div open and button to open div

Tags: javascript, html, button, delay

Hi I'm struggling to get this to work.

Below code works fine on its own. If I click the button, it toggles the `.sidebar-form` `div`. Great!

```
$( ".sidebar-button" ).click(function() {
  $( ".sidebar-form" ).toggle('2000');
});
```

But I also want the `div` to auto open after 10 seconds.

```
$( ".sidebar-form" ).delay('10000');
```

This works BUT the click stops working totally when I add the `.delay`.

Any ideas if they could work together?

Comment: Please share your markup.

Comment: `setTimeout` is where you go.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTimeout` with a timeout of 10 sec and in callback of that toggle the state of the div.

```
$( ".sidebar-button" ).click(function() {
  $( ".sidebar-form" ).toggle('2000');
  setTimeout(function(){
    $( ".sidebar-form" ).show('2000');
  }, 10*1000)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `delay` and `show`

```
$( ".sidebar-form" ).toggle('2000');
$( ".sidebar-form" ).delay(10000).show(0)
```

or

```
$( ".sidebar-form" ).hide(2000).delay(10000).show(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the comments I have figured it out. this seems to work for me. 
first hide the div... then setTimeout to delay show. And the button works.

```
$( ".sidebar-form" ).hide();

    setTimeout(function() {
                $('.sidebar-form').show("2000");
         }, 5000);

$( ".sidebar-button" ).click(function() {
  $( ".sidebar-form" ).toggle('2000');
});
```